# Ember templates not displaying

Tags: django, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am following [this](http://dustinfarris.com/2013/11/29/django-ember-token-authentication.html) guide to set up token authentication for ember.js and django, but none of the handlebar templates are rendered.  I've stripped out most of the code to find the smallest failing example:

In "index.html"

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% verbatim %}
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Hello world</h2>
        {{outlet}}
      </script>
    {% endverbatim %}
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/ember/ember.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/build/ember-data-django-rest-adapter.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'application.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In "application.js"

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({});
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.DjangoRESTSerializer.extend({});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: 'auth'
});

App.AuthController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    token: null,

    hasValidToken: function() {
        return false;
    }.property('token')
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log('ok...');
        console.log(this.controllerFor('auth').hasValidToken());
    }
});
```

The problem appears to be in `hasValidToken` because the console logs "ok..." but nothing after that.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasValidToken` is a computed property, as such you'll need to use a getter on it.

```
console.log(this.controllerFor('auth').get('hasValidToken'));
```

Comment: Thanks. This was part of the problem.  The other part was django-debug-toolbar, which loads it's own jquery library.  Not sure what the clash was exactly, but disabling it sorted it out.